# In Yaml how can I trigger a pipeline to run at a specific time for a specific stage?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have currently 2 stages (DEV and Testing).

I would like to run a deployment to the Testing stage every time at midnight.

I read the documentation from Microsoft:

```
# YAML file in the main branch
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

According to that, it will run my pipeline on the `main` branch every midnight. However, I'll like to just run the deployment pipeline on a specific stage (Testing). How can I achieve that?

*Update*: I have looked at the proposed duplicate.  That only answers how to schedule a release, but not the essential part of my question -- How to schedule it within a specific environment.  I do not want the pipeline to run on the first environment, I want it to run on the second environment only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Build.Reason` predefined variable, [scroll down a little from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) for more info.

It would look something like this:

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main

stages:
- ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'Schedule'): # Runs only when not scheduled
  - stage: Dev
    jobs:
    - job: SomeDevJob
      steps:
      - powershell: "Running on Dev!"

- stage: Testing # Always runs
  jobs:
  - job: SomeTestJob
    steps:
    - powershell: "Running on Testing!"
```

The YAML might not be 100% correct, but I'm sure you can get there with this info. Check out the docs page about [Expressions and Conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) for a little more context.